# Check when Sound is Finished c#

Tags: c#, audio

How would I check when a sound I have played is Finished?
I am using C#.Net Winforms and my code for playing the sound is:

```
SoundPlayer s = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\intro.wav");
        s.Play();
```

For anyone who needs to know the import, it is `using System.Media;`

So I need to know when my Sound has finished playing, and then I need to run some code. I know I could probably use a timer, but I want to refrain from doing that for specific reasons.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default SoundPlayer runs on a separate thread but there is a method to play a sound on the current thread. See [PlaySync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync.aspx)

```
private SoundPlayer Player = new SoundPlayer();
private void loadSoundAsync()
{
    // Note: You may need to change the location specified based on
    // the location of the sound to be played.
    this.Player.SoundLocation = "http://www.tailspintoys.com/sounds/stop.wav";
    this.Player.LoadAsync();
}

private void Player_LoadCompleted (
          object sender, 
          System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Player.IsLoadCompleted)
    {
        this.Player.PlaySync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a task and *await* it *without blocking* your UI thread...

```
async void Test()
{
    using (var player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Alarm01.wav"))
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { player.Load(); player.PlaySync(); });
        MessageBox.Show("Finished. Now you can run your code here");
    }
}
```